# WPF DropShadowEffect with AllowsTransparency="True"

Tags: wpf, styles, dropshadow

I want to create Non-Rectangular Window with `DropShadowEffect` on it. I found [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2009/10/27/create-a-login-window-in-wpf.aspx) article how to do this. However `DropShadowEffect` is not shown when running this code. On screenshots you can see that `DropShadowEffect` is present, but it's not working for me.

How I can use `DropShadowEffect` with `AllowsTransparency` set to True?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tried the following code in [Kaxaml](http://web.archive.org/web/20120502001646/http://www.kaxaml.com/) and got a rounded box with a drop shadow.

[image: Rounded box with drop shadow]

I suggest you try Kaxaml too, just to separate your experiments from whatever other code you might have. If this exact code does **not** show a drop shadow, then the problem must be with your system.

```
<Window
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
  WindowStyle="None"
  AllowsTransparency="True"
  Background="Transparent"
  >
  
<Border CornerRadius="10"
        BorderBrush="Gray"
        BorderThickness="3"
        Background="AliceBlue"
        Margin="24"
        Padding="4"
        Width="100"
        Height="100"
        >
  <Border.Effect>
    <DropShadowEffect Color="Gray"
                      Opacity=".50"
                      ShadowDepth="16" />
  </Border.Effect>
  
  <Grid Background="AliceBlue">
      <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Hello world.</TextBlock>
  </Grid>
  </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: You're right. This code works on other computer, but not on my. Thanks for help.